# How to group multiple blocks into one big block

Tags: blocks, theming

I have a website with Drupal 7 and the customer just asked to make it "responsive design".

I need, for the design to respond correctly, to group some blocks I already have into some bigger blocks, on which i can apply the specific classes I need.

Region aren't valid for me because the website is already built and it would be really messy to change it just to add regions.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you just wrap your blocks in div's that have the classes you need? Maybe by using `$block['content']['#prefix'] = '<div class="row">';` `$block['content']['#suffix'] = '</div>';`? By blocks do you mean custom blocks defined in a module via `hook_block_view()` or custom blocks that are just markup (tile and content) added from the admin/structure/blocks page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Block Group](http://drupal.org/project/blockgroup) module may help you

> This module extends the standard drupal block system with block
>   groups. Each block group provides a new block as well as a
>   corresponding region. Child blocks can be moved into any group region.
>   The position and the settings of the parent block are propagated to
>   its children. Also block groups are nestable.

Take a look. I am not sure how it will integrate with responsive style.