# Composite block from multiple other blocks + layout

Tags: 8, blocks

I would like to create a block consisting of multiple other blocks, combined with a layout or some other kind of wrapper html.

A typical example would be a footer with 4 columns containing a menu, some custom text, etc.

The entire thing should be configurable in the UI and then exportable to the CMI system.

### Known solutions

I know that this is possible in Drupal 7 using [renderkit](https://drupal.org/project/renderkit) + [cfrblock](https://drupal.org/project/cfrblock). However this has not been ported to Drupal 8 (yet). I will get there eventually, but atm I would like to find out if another solution might already exist.

EDIT:
On D8 there is [blockgroup](https://drupal.org/project/blockgroup), but it does not really work for me.

### Related issues

[How to group multiple blocks into one big block](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50599/how-to-group-multiple-blocks-into-one-big-block) I think this is for D7.

Thanks!

Comment: Blockgroup will allow you to create groups of blocks. Other than that, all I can think of is Paragraphs in blocks.

Comment: I had tried blockgroup, but my mistake was to name the block group the same as the theme region :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [blockgroup](https://drupal.org/project/blockgroup). Add [block_class](https://drupal.org/project/block_class) if needed.

When creating the block groups, make sure that the machine name does not clash with existing theme region machine names! (from any theme, ideally)

After you created a block group, it will show up in two ways in the blocks UI:

- As a new theme region (if you avoided the name clash)
- As a block that can be placed.

Block class allows to add classes (e.g. bootstrap grid classes) to each block and block group.

This is not 100% what you would get with a layout, but it is getting close, and will be sufficient in many cases.